# Converting html to pdf after clicking on download button in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pdf

I have created a resume builder application.User enters all required details and i am storing all details in database. Then i am fetching those records and displaying it in different templates. I have created 3 templates. Now I want to give download as pdf and download as docx two download buttons. Once user clicks on any of buttons file will be downloaded in their chosen format. Either pdf or docx.

Is it possible to achieve in codeigniter?

i used Tcpdf

Controller Code is

```js
the code written in controller download $this - > load - > library("Pdf");
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
// set auto page breaks
$pdf - > SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
// set image scale factor
$pdf - > setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
// Add a page
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf - > AddPage();
// Set some content to print 
$html = $this - > load - > view('resume/res_template1_view', array('left_sidebar' => 'sidebar/left_sidebar', '             right_sidebar' => 'sidebar/right_sidebar'), $data, TRUE);
// Print text using writeHTMLCell()
$pdf - > writeHTML($html, 0, 0, '', '', 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
//$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, ''); 

// Close and output PDF document
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf - > Output('resume.pdf', 'D');
```

Comment: Google for something like "php html2pdf". Regarding `.docx` files `PHPOffice/PHPWord` could be your choice.

Comment: you can use https://parall.ax/products/jspdf this too. Very well documented.

Comment: You can use Mpdf `https://davidsimpson.me/2013/05/19/using-mpdf-with-codeigniter/` or `http://www.w3school.info/2016/02/08/convert-html-to-pdf-in-codeigniter-using-mpdf/`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use some library in CI to achieve this. Please check below.
you can use Html2Pdf for CI3 library. https://github.com/shyamshingadiya/HTML2PDF-CI3

> How to Use

There are 4 options you a required to set in order to create a PDF; folder, filename, paper and HTML

```
//Load the library
$this->load->library('html2pdf');

//Set folder to save PDF to
$this->html2pdf->folder('./assets/pdfs/');

//Set the filename to save/download as
$this->html2pdf->filename('test.pdf');

//Set the paper defaults
$this->html2pdf->paper('a4', 'portrait');

//Load html view
$this->html2pdf->html(<h1>Some Title</h1><p>Some content in here</p>);
```

The create function has two options `'save'` and `'download'`. Save will just write the PDF to the folder you choose in the settings. Download will force the PDF to download in the clients browser.

```
//Create the PDF
$this->html2pdf->create('save');
```

**Advanced usage**

Theres no reason why you can't build and pass a view to the `html()` function. Also note the `create()` function will return the saved path if you choose the `'save'` option.

```
$data = array(
    'title' => 'PDF Created',
    'message' => 'Hello World!'
);

//Load html view
$this->html2pdf->html($this->load->view('pdf', $data, true));

if($path = $this->html2pdf->create('save')) {
    //PDF was successfully saved or downloaded
    echo 'PDF saved to: ' . $path;
}
```

Please check above mentioned solution. Let me know if it not works.

Comment: I used Tcpdf. Download working properly. But downloaded pdf file is empty if i pass vlaue as $this->load->view to $html variable.

Comment: if i directly write some html in $html the downloaded pdf contains those html css values

Comment: Okay, Now can you print your `$html` and check weather you are getting value or not.

Comment: view  is not loading into $html.Is it not possible to load the view directly to a variable?

Comment: `$variable = $this->load->view('view_name',$data, true);` you can use this.

Comment: Now it contains content.... Css is Not working properly. Like I have Side bar in one resume template. its not taking that sidebar css